# Calculation of number density from material density

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, material-science

Material density is given by $ \rho =m/V$, where $m$ is mass and $V$ is volume.
Again number density given by $n=N/V$, where $N$ is the total number of particle. How can I calculate number density $n$ from material density $ \rho $.

Comment: You need to know the mass per particle $\mu$. Then number of particles = total mass / mass per particle, $N = m/\mu$.

Answer (score 3):

For atoms or molecules of a well-defined molecular mass M (in units of kg/mole), the number density can be expressed in terms of the mass density of a substance ρ (in units of kg/m3) as
 $$ n=\frac{N_{\rm A}}{M}\rho$$

Note that the ratio M/NA is the mass of a single atom or molecule in units of kg.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the material as $\mathrm{Ti}_6\mathrm{Al}_4\mathrm{V}$,
Atomic mass = $44.01$ g/mol
Using Avagadro constant $6.02214076 \times 10^{23}~\mathrm{mol}^{-1}$
1 element weight = $7.31 \times 10^{-23}$ g/element = $7.31\times 10^{-26}$ kg/element
Density = $4420$ kg/$m^3$
So, $4420$ kg has $6.05\times 10^{28}$ elements
And, we can say number density = $6.05\times 10^{28}$ elements/$m^3$